# converting a void * to an array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, memcpy

I need to convert an array an place it in a struct that has a void* element and back to another array:

```
unsigned short array[size];
//do something to the array

typedef struct ck{

void * arg1;
void * arg2;
void * arg3;


} argCookie;


argCookie myCookie;

myCookie.arg2=malloc(sizeof(array));//alloc the necessary space
memcpy(myCookie.arg2,&array,sizeof(array));//copy the entire array there


//later....


unsigned short otherArray[size];
otherArray=*((unsigned short**)aCookie.arg2);
```

It happens that this last line won't compile...
Why is that? obviously I've messed up somewhere...

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to copy `aCookie.arg2` into `otherArray`, use `memcpy` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy arrays by assigning it a pointer, arrays are not pointers, and you cannot assign to an array, you can only assign to elements of an array.

You can use memcpy() to copy into your array:

```
//use array, or &array[0] in memcpy,
//&array is the wrong intent (though it'll likely not matter in this case
memcpy(myCookie.arg2,array,sizeof(array));

//later....

unsigned short otherArray[size];
memcpy(otherArray, myCookie.arg2, size);
```

That assumes you know `size` , otherwise you need to place the size in one of your cookies as well.
Depending on what you need, you might not need to copy into `otherArray`, just use the data from the cookie directly:

```
unsigned short *tmp = aCookie.arg2;
//use `tmp` instead of otherArray.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to arrays. Instead of

```
otherArray=*((unsigned short**)aCookie.arg2);
```

just use `memcpy` again, if you know the size:

```
memcpy(&otherArray, aCookie.arg2, size*sizeof(unsigned short));
```

If you don't know the size, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned short* otherArray = (unsigned short*)aCookie.arg2
```

Then you can use `otherArray[n]` to access the elements. Beware of an out-of-bound index.